# Reference other eclipse projects using gradle

Tags: java, eclipse, build, gradle

For my workspace I have:

- ProjectA (Core Api project using maven for build management)
- ProjectB (Spring Rest Webservice using Gradle for build management)

What is the best way to reference ProjectA from ProjectB?

Answer (score 0):

install your ProjectA in local maven repository and use mavenLocal from ProjectB gradle.
In projectB gradle, make sure to include project A dependency.
Refer to this post for details: http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/how_to_use_maven_local_repository_for_gradle_build